# What is a kill streak in campaign?

Tags: battlefield-4

I notice in campaign mode there are kill streaks and multi-kills. If I get a kill streak notification I notice that if I kill another enemy without dying my next kill isn't marked as part of the kill streak. It seems like kill streak is actually a delayed multi-kill. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kill streak is how many kills you get without receiving damage.
Multi-kills is killing 2 or more enemies in a very short amount of time.